# Включить очереди Triage и Help&Improvement на нашем сайте

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок, новые-участники

На Stack Overflow есть две очереди проверок, которых у нас нет:

- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) (Сортировка) — сюда попадают все вопросы от участников с низкой репутацией (а не только первые). Вопрос можно отметить как хороший, закрыть (доступно меню тревог), отправить в очередь на улучшение. Ну и пропустить можно.
- [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/) (Помощь и улучшение). Сюда попадают вопросы, которым нужна рука редактора. Наполняется очередь из Triage и, возможно, ещё откуда-то.

Хочу, чтобы они появились и у нас. Вот что это нам даст:

- Больше внимания к вопросам от новых участников. Им часто нужны подсказки и указания на то, как хорошо сформулировать вопрос, как разобраться с форматированием и т.п. Больше внимания — это и больше голосов за хорошие вопросы.
- Быстрее реакция на вопросы низкого качества. В очереди Triage можно даже ставить тревоги, в отличие от очереди «низкого качества». Но они друг друга не дублируют, т.к. во вторую нередко попадают старые вопросы, а также все ответы.
- Больше шансов, что криво отформатированное сообщение будет исправлено.
- Ещё два золотых знака для ударников в очередях проверок. =)
- (дополняйте)

Про техническую возможность включения очередей обещал разузнать Nicolas Chabanovsky.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, не надо.

Одно дело enSO, где полно народу и автоматизированные средства не справляются, а другое дело тут. В таком случае не слишком хорошее сообщение должно будет пройти две очереди вместо одной, т. е. надо вдвое больше проверяющих. Плюс, придётся проверять и хорошие сообщения от новичков. У нас не так много народу, чтобы необоснованно забивать очереди.

Answer (score 5):

Эти очереди нужны только тогда, когда поток новых вопросов превышает возможности высокореповых пользователей их отслеживать. Когда поток маленький (порядка 100 вопросов в день и меньше), не составляет труда пройтись по всем вопросам за день и проверить качество. Так как модерирующих пользователей достаточно много, то вопросы обычно не остаются без внимания.

На большом же СО новые вопросы в день исчисляются тысячами, и даже при фильтрации по метке практически невозможно уследить за новыми вопросами по популярным меткам. Эти очереди придуманы как решение этой проблемы: "однозадачные" процедуры обработки постов мутируют в страшного монстра с ветвлениями по многим очередям, чтобы посты, которые можно спасти, не затерялись в общем потоке.

В общем и целом, эти очереди на нашем сайте будут совершенно бесполезны. Гораздо проще просто просмотреть список новых вопросов, а не гонять все посты по нескольким очередям.

Comment: я как-то попробовал в прошлом году просматривать насквозь весь наш *маленький* поток. не помню, на сколько дней меня «хватило». то ли на два, то ли на три. и это были только вопросы.

Comment: Добавлю, что на SO доступ к указанным очередям с гораздо более низким уровнем репутации. Т. е. тем, кто ещё много не набрал, нормальную проверку не доверяют, а пустить на сортировку - без проблем.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin План в том, что пользователи невольно проверяю качество вопросов по темам, которыми интересуются. Размер сайта, когда можно без проблем читать совсем все вопросы на постоянной основе, Ру.СО перерос. :)